# request api in foreach

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, settimeout

I have an `array` of data, against which I query an `api` using `request`. With a `callback` executing after each response for the request that is made. However, in doing so, I end up launching parallel requests for all the items in the array. Here is what I am doing:

```
exports.getData = function(arr, cb){
    arr.forEach(function(data){
        var query = {
            //some data here
        };
       request({
           url: 'http://x/y',
           json: query,
           method: 'POST',
           headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
           }
       }, function(error, res, body){
           if (error){
               console.log(error);
           } else{
               cb(res.body);
           }
       });
    });
};
```

I want to `setTimeOut` of `x seconds` in the above code. Should I implement a naive delay after each request? Or something else?

Comment: so you want to make your request synchronous?

Comment: Use promises to launch your callback after all requests are complete

Comment: Is there a problem with the requests being asynchronous?  Typically this would be much better for application performance such that you are not blocking each loop iteration waiting for previous request to be fulfilled.

Comment: @MikeBrant the problem is sending requests to server in burst mode.. Even in asynchronous, wouldnt I be essentially be doing the same?

Comment: @faizanjehangir Use [`async.queue()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue), much better than playing with timeouts. And you're right, it's a bad idea to fire a lot of requests to an API at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated : parallel request to series of request.**

You should use series of request. use `async` module. see below

```
exports.getData = function(arr, cb){

  // make an array of function
  var funcArray = [];

  arr.forEach(function(data){
      var query = {
          //some data here
      };

     funcArray.push(function(callback){    
        request({
           url: 'http://x/y',
           json: query,
           method: 'POST',
           headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
           }
        }, function(error, res, body){
           // 5 second interval for each request
           setTimeout(function(){ callback(error, body); }, 5000);
        });
      });
  });


  // now run all tasks on series
  async.series(funcArray,function(err, result){

      // now you will get result for all request

      // handle error
      // do what ever you want with result
  });
}
```

Comment: How do I add `timeout` between each request made?

Comment: then you should use `async.series`. now make delay before executing callback.
because next request will be executed when you call the callback function.

`setTimeout(function(){ callback(error, body); }, 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

forEach loop will ideally end in no time, so you can first add all query parameters in queryPool and then execute them one by one.

You can refer to this code.

```js
exports.getData = function(arr, cb){
    var queryPool = [];
    function execQuery(){
       if(queryPool.length == 0) return
       var query = queryPool.slice(0,1)
       queryPool = queryPool.slice(1,queryPool.length)
       request({
           url: 'http://x/y',
           json: query,
           method: 'POST',
           headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
           }
       }, function(error, res, body){
           if (error){
               console.log(error);
           } else{
               cb(res.body);
           }
           execQuery();
       });
    }
    arr.forEach(function(data){
        var query = {
            //some data here
        };
       queryPool.push(query);
    });
    execQuery();
};
```

This code assumes function given in request executes in all conditions, failure or success.